# how can I implement a image gallery in table layout?

Tags: android

I would like to implement a gallery like Facebook does with Photos on my android app, I mean, show all pictures into an ScrollView or a TableLayout.
I tried [Gallery](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html), but it just shows a row with three thumbnails and I want the full screen with thumbnails.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a `GridView` with a custom `Adapter`.  Here is an [example](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html).

Answer (score 0):

Check grid view, that will be that what you need, in android you can also make small thumbnails from big picture.
In grid view you have to specify some information check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html)